# Find needed header file

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded, esp8266

I'm programming in `C` a device (`ESP8266`) whose documentation explains each function or data structure of the SDK, but doesn't tell where to locate the corresponding header file, so every time I need to search them using `grep` and annoying regex.

Which is in these cases the best/common practice to "browse" the SDK and find headers?
I usually use `nano` and `Sublime Text` as editor (on GNU/Linux and Mac OS X) but any other solution are appreciated.

Comment: You could replace repeatedly grepping with a one-line shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally just use `find` + `grep` for this, e.g. to find the definition of `foo`:

```
$ find /path/to/SDK -name \*.h -exec grep foo {} /dev/null \;
```

Comment: Very handy! Just to know, what is the use of `/dev/null` ?

Comment: If you don't add the `/dev/null` then `grep` thinks it's just grepping a single file and doesn't list the file name for any matches. I think you can also achieve the same effect by passing the `-l` switch to `grep`, but old habits die hard.

Comment: Or even just `grep foo $(find /path/to/SDK -name \*.h)`